# GUI для приложения, работающего в среде WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

Добрый день, прошу помощи в написании GUI для приложения, работающего в среде WPF.
Мне непонятно как сдлать следующую вещь:
Нужно создать Listview, при этом программно добавлять в него картинки (png), по нажатию кнопки, к примеру. Listview при этом должен расширяться горизонтально (в смысле размер его должен оставаться фиксированным, просто контент должен разрастаться, ). По нажатию на элемент в Listview, он должен загружаться в Image на форме.
Я не прошу писать за меня код и делать мое задание, просто ткните носом в какие-нибудь примеры или там копипастнете куски кода.  Очень прошу, ибо сильно надо.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выучите MVVM, это текущий правильный pattern. Легко гуглится, хотя большинство хороших статей на английском языке.

Для MVVM ваша задача выглядит так:

1. Заводите `ViewModel`-тип, задающий картинку.
2. Во `ViewModel` заведите `ObservableCollection`, которая содержит список картинок.
3. Во `ViewModel` заведите свойство, соответствующее выбранному элементу в `ListView`.
4. Добавьте во `View` `Binding`: `ItemsSource` в `ListView` на `ObservableCollection`, `SelectedItem` на свойство из пункта 3 (two-way), `Image` на форме — тоже на свойство из пункта 3.
5. По нажатию кнопки отправляйте команду, на которой во `ViewModel` добавляйте новый элемент в `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, пойду читать. Надкюсь это поможет мне понять еще и сам WPF в частности.

Comment: Пожалуйста!